# Slack. Найти id пользователя по его username

Tags: slack

Использую Slack Bot Web API. 
Нужно получить ИД юзера в формате код D7PRX67LZ по его username.

Существует метод [users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list). Но он выдает ВСЕХ юзеров. Соответсвенно придет пробегать по ним и фильтровать.

Я понимаю, что можно закешировать/сохранить в локальную БД.

Вопрос: 
 - существует ли способ получить эту информацию без запроса всех юзеров и их фильтрации? 
 - существуют ли библиотеки, которые могут облегчить этот процесс ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел как это можно сделать - просто перед именем пользователя поставьте '@'.

Пример:

```
web.chat.postMessage('@' + usename, "Hello user")
```